# apache flink org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length when writing string to HDFS

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Exploring how to write to an HDFS from apache flink I tried the following:

```
 val sink: StreamingFileSink[String] = StreamingFileSink
      .forRowFormat(new Path("hdfs://localhost:50070/mydata"), new SimpleStringEncoder[String]("UTF-8"))
      .withRollingPolicy(
        DefaultRollingPolicy.builder()
          .withRolloverInterval(Duration.ofMinutes(15))
          .withInactivityInterval(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
          .withMaxPartSize(1024 * 1024 * 1024)
          .build())
      .build()
```

I run a Hive cluster locally quite similar to [this docker-compose.yaml](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hive/blob/master/docker-compose.yml).

But writing completely fails with `org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length`

I verified the port is the correct one and added the following to `hadoop-hive.env` ([see here](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hive/blob/master/hadoop-hive.env)):

```
HIVE_SITE_CONF_ipc_maximum_data_length=134217728
```

Is this the correct way to define increase the data length through an environment variable? Or could the problem be somewhere else?

Comment: Based on your newer question, your namenode isn't running on 50070

Comment: That should be the port when addressed from the outside of docker... But I see there is an issue with that

Comment: If you're using Hadoop 3, it isn't https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L9

Comment: I started actually off with this one: https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hive/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: But I now assume I should probably also open port `9870:9870`...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the env file used by the namenode

If you have this line, then that's the namenode address you should be using

```
CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:8020
```

If running code from the host, you might run into similar network issues because the client needs to be able to connect directly to the datanodes, which it won't easily be able to. The only reasonable workaround is to run your code in a container on the same Docker network